# Temporary list won't append at each iteration

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm a beginner and I have this piece of code here:

```
alleles=['DPY','DPX']
n_dict={'DPY':[['AA561_P4',5781],['AA562_P2',5712]],'DPX':[['AA561_P3',5324],['AA565_P2',5742]]}
n_list = []
for item in alleles:
    f_list=[item]
    for sub in n_dict[item]:
        t=sub[0].split('_')
        t1=t[1]+','+t[0]
        f_list.append(t1)
    n_list.append(f_list)
print(f_list)
```

It's supposed to go through each item in allele and use the item as a key to recover a list of lists. Subsequently for each item (sub) in the list of lists, it has to take the element at the zero position and re-arrange it and append this re-arranged string to a list(f_list). Finally, once it has gone through the complete list of lists for an allele, it has to append the list of strings (f_list) to n_list.

Instead of giving a list of lists, with each list containing a list of re-arranged strings, I get only the last list of strings. I suspect it may be a problem that could be fixed the .copy module but I still have not found a solution.

Comment: How do you expect the result to look like (example) ? Your description sounds more complicated as it is.

Comment: `print(n_list)`, it seems to give you what you need.

Comment: What you have is a typo

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you define your f_list variable inside the loop. As such the result of the first iteration gets overwritten with the one from the next, throwing away its results. Moving the initial definition of f_list up by a line, initialising it to an empty list, and appending item to it inside the loop should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cahnge the following two lines of code:

```
    n_list.append(f_list)
print(n_list)
```

into

```
    n_list.append(list(f_list))
print(n_list)
```

I think is what you are looking for.